# Parse.com query for column that is not null on iOS

Tags: ios, mongodb, parse-platform

This should be a simple task but it's causing me grief. I have objects that look like this in the database:

```
{
  "objectId": "abcdefg1",
  "comment": null
},
{
  "objectId": "abcdefg2",
  "comment": "Some text as a comment"
}
```

I'm trying to query for only records that have comment text on iOS. I'm executing the following query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Review"];
[query whereKeyExists:@"comment"];
```

When it's executed I'm getting the two results listed above when I'm expecting only one. Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use this query, you should let abcdefg1 without "comment"(only {"objectId": "abcdefg1"}).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh...naturally I just figured it out. Here is the solution:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Review"];
[query whereKey:@"comment" notEqualTo:[NSNull null]];
```

This returns me the one object I expected. I need to pay attention to the documentation better.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-data-types